# Show comments to unregistered users

Tags: comments

I require users to register in order to post comments on www.bbleaks.com However, using this feature in wordpress causes the comments to be hidden if you aren't logged in. How can I show the comments even if you aren't logged in?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that this is an issue with a theme or plugin you're using.  The comments should still show for non-logged in users even if you require users to be logged in to post new comments.

Comment: Yes, I would agree. I would maybe replace your comments.php file (assuming your theme uses one) with one from another style. You might have to go and replace some styling elements, but it might at least fix your problem. If it doesn't you could always go back to the old comments.php.

Answer (score 1):

Both display of comments and comment form should be handled in `comments.php` (or other template designated for that by theme).

While [`comment_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) function does check if registration is required (and doesn't output form to unregistered users in such case) [`wp_list_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) does not perform such check, since it isn't in line with native logic of this setting.

I had grabbed copy of Elegant News theme you are using on site and I don't see explicit additional conditions in `comments.php`. Either your description of issue is missing some details or is cause by a plugin or other additional code.